# Python plot Legend Key Format

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a set of data in python. I'm using matplotlib.pyplot library to do this.

I got everything working, but I have this one issue where the last key in the legend comes out with a weird format than the others. I tried to do different settings to get this fixed with no luck so far... Can anyone help me fix that CH4 (A) to show in the same format as the other keys?

The format looks much like this in the plot (I cannot post picture until I get 10 reputations

CH1 (A)

CH2 (A)

CH3 (A)

CH4

(A

)

Here is my code to set up legend.

```
legends = data[16]
legends = legends.split(",")

if numChannels == 1:
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,1], label=legends[1] + " (" + units[1] + ")")
elif numChannels == 2:
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,1], label=legends[1] + " (" + units[1] + ")")
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,2], label=legends[2] + " (" + units[2] + ")")
elif numChannels == 3:
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,1], label=legends[1] + " (" + units[1] + ")")
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,2], label=legends[2] + " (" + units[2] + ")")
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,3], label=legends[3] + " (" + units[3] + ")")
elif numChannels == 4:
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,1], label=legends[1] + " (" + units[1] + ")")
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,2], label=legends[2] + " (" + units[2] + ")")
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,3], label=legends[3] + " (" + units[3] + ")")
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,4], label=legends[4] + " (" + units[4] + ")")
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.xlabel(legends[0])
plt.ylabel("Data")
plt.title(filestr)
plt.show()
```

legends is data I am reading in from a .csv file. I'm not really sure why this happens. This only happens to the last legend. E.g. if I have 4 data set and plot 3, they come out fine, but if I plot all 4 or only have 1 data set and plot, the key is formatted differently as shown above.

Comment: Please give a demonstrating minimal code. [ask]

Comment: I put a bit more of the code. that's about all the code I have for plotting. Rest of my code is just for parsing data. Also, it doesn't matter if I use a data I read from the file or use a hard coded string variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you `units[4]` data may contain some newline characters (`\n`) which are causing the strange legend format. If you setup the legend and units strings manually, you get what looks like correct formatting,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

raw = np.random.random((20,5))
legends = [" ", "CH1 ","CH2 ","CH3 ","CH4 "]
units = [" ", "A","A","A","A"]
numChannels = 4

if numChannels == 1:
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,1], label=legends[1] + " (" + units[1] + ")")
elif numChannels == 2:
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,1], label=legends[1] + " (" + units[1] + ")")
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,2], label=legends[2] + " (" + units[2] + ")")
elif numChannels == 3:
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,1], label=legends[1] + " (" + units[1] + ")")
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,2], label=legends[2] + " (" + units[2] + ")")
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,3], label=legends[3] + " (" + units[3] + ")")
elif numChannels == 4:
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,1], label=legends[1] + " (" + units[1] + ")")
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,2], label=legends[2] + " (" + units[2] + ")")
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,3], label=legends[3] + " (" + units[3] + ")")
    plt.plot(raw[:,0],raw[:,4], label=legends[4] + " (" + units[4] + ")")
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.xlabel(legends[0])
plt.ylabel("Data")
plt.show()
```

which gives,
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about the whitespace at the end of the csv files which was causing the weird formatting. All I had to do was strip before splitting!